# Life cycle of controller is not called

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have two controllers with UI(xib), that are A and B. Now I want to present any on of them on C. To select the from A and B, I create a new controller D which decide whom to show (A or B). Now It is like C present D. And D has either A or B as a child view controller.

from C i present D like :

```
[self presentViewController:D animated:YES completion:nil]
```

and D has child view controller from (A or B) like :

```
[self addChildViewController:(A/B)];
[self didMoveToParentViewController:(A/B)];
```

Now the problem is the life cycle of child view controller is not called.
I also use [(A/B) beginAppearanceTransition:YES animated:NO]; But using this only first time life cycle is called.
Does anyone know who to solve it?

Comment: What does "the life cycle of child view controller is not called" mean?

Comment: It should be`[(A/B) didMoveToParentViewController:self];` in D

Comment: assuming that "life cycle" means having viewDidLoad() called in each viewController, did you properly called [super viewDidLoad]  in A and B viewDidLoad() method?

Comment: "the life cycle of child view controller is not called" means the methods viewwillappear and viewdidappear of A/B are not call.

Comment: @Mikael yes i called [super viewDidLoad]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the `didMoveToParentViewController:` method. The parameter of this method should be the container. Assuming the `self` is D, after you add (A/B) to D by invoking `[self addChildViewController:(A/B)]` and the animation transition ends , you should invoke `[(A/B) didMoveToParentViewController:self]`; In the similar way, when you need remove (A/B), you invoke `[(A/B) removeFromParentViewController]`, then the `didMoveToParentViewController:` will be automatically invoked.

This is the apple's document to explain this:

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must
>   call the didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view
>   controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or,
>   if there is no transition, immediately after calling the
>   addChildViewController: method. The removeFromParentViewController
>   method automatically calls the didMoveToParentViewController: method
>   of the child view controller after it removes the child.

Hope this maybe help.